# How to add preview images to my plugin?

Tags: php, shopware

I've searched Shopware's official documentation about how to add my own preview images (similar to this https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AIM37toCFNs/maxresdefault.jpg) to my plugin but I couldn't find any info about this.

I've also looked at the source code of a few plugins from the marketplace and some of them didn't have any code regarding adding a preview image while others had but it was so entangled and messed up that I didn't quite understand how to do it.

Comment: What plugin system you use? Do you want to add plugin description? Can you provide more details?

Comment: I'm using Shopware's MVC system. No, I don't want to add plugin description as I already have it. The only thing that I don't know how to do at this moment is setting up preview images for the plugin, like this one has https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AIM37toCFNs/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I think you should add your plugin to shopware store, but if you find solution - please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to add those pictures you have to publish your plugin in the shopware store.  These images are coming from the store.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to insert a `plugin.png` file at the same level as the resources folder

Comment: I already have the `plugin.png` file but that's not what I'm looking for because this just adds a small icon.